# How much space is allocated for following code?

Tags: c, pointers

How much space is allocated by the expression

```
int *a[10];
```

If size of `int` is `4` and size of `int pointer` is `2`.

options are 2, 4, 20, 40

I am poor at pointers please help me.

Comment: What do you think, and why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In declaration `int *a[10]`, `a` is array of pointer to int of 10 size, so size = `sizeof (int*) * 10`.

You can apply sizeof operator to print its size:

```
printf("sizeof = %zu", sizeof(a));
```

If suppose in some system sizeof pointer to int is 2  (as you says in question) then size will be 20 bytes.

Answer (score 2):

This will allocate an array of 10 integer pointers, if the size of an int pointer is 2, this takes up 20 bytes.

Answer (score 1):

Write a little C program with `printf ("sizeof (a)= %d\n", sizeof (a));`

It should print "20" if sizeof *int == 2 (like an old DOS machine), and "40" if sizeof *int == 4.

EXAMPLE (32-bit MSVC compile):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int
main () {
  int * a[10];
  printf ("sizeof(int)=%d, sizeof (*int)=%d, sizeof (a)=%d\n", 
    sizeof(int), sizeof (int*), sizeof (a));
  return 0;
}
```

> sizeof(int)=4, sizeof (*int)=4, sizeof (a)=40